# Unable to override \Magento\Directory\Block\Data class-magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks, class, extend, magento2.4.4

Can anybody help me to add a class in getCountryHtmlSelect()

I have tried to override \Magento\Directory\Block\Data file using plugin but i can't extend that so i go for perference.
added code in di.xml and created file in Vendor\Module\Block\Data please check the code below

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Data extends \Magento\Directory\Block\Data
{

    public function getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country')
    {
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('TEST: ' . __METHOD__, ['group' => 'TEST', 'method' => __METHOD__]);
        if ($defValue === null) {
            $defValue = $this->getCountryId();
        }
        $cacheKey = 'DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_SELECT_STORE_' . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        $cache = $this->_configCacheType->load($cacheKey);
        if ($cache) {
            $options = $this->getSerializer()->unserialize($cache);
        } else {
            $options = $this->getCountryCollection()
                ->setForegroundCountries($this->getTopDestinations())
                ->toOptionArray();
            $this->_configCacheType->save($this->getSerializer()->serialize($options), $cacheKey);
        }
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class
        )->setName(
            $name
        )->setId(
            $id
        )->setTitle(
            $this->escapeHtmlAttr(__($title))
        )->setValue(
            $defValue
        )->setClass(
            'class-name'
        )->setOptions(
            $options
        )->setExtraParams(
            'data-validate="{\'validate-select\':true}"'
        )->getHtml();

        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('TEST: ' . __METHOD__);
        return $html;
    
    }

   
}
```

and my di.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Block\Data" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Data" />
</config>
```

cleared cache and compile the code shows no error.

can anybody give me an idea about this?

Thnaks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

class Data extends \Magento\Directory\Block\Data
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config
     */
    protected $_configCacheType;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_regionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_countryCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $_jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $directoryHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface
     */
    private $serializer;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config $configCacheType
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config $configCacheType,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
        $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->_configCacheType = $configCacheType;
        $this->_regionCollectionFactory = $regionCollectionFactory;
        $this->_countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $directoryHelper,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $configCacheType,
            $regionCollectionFactory,
            $countryCollectionFactory,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns country html select
     *
     * @param null|string $defValue
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $id
     * @param string $title
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country')
    {
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('TEST: ' . __METHOD__, ['group' => 'TEST', 'method' => __METHOD__]);
        if ($defValue === null) {
            $defValue = $this->getCountryId();
        }
        $cacheKey = 'DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_SELECT_STORE_' . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        $cache = $this->_configCacheType->load($cacheKey);
        if ($cache) {
            $options = $this->getSerializer()->unserialize($cache);
        } else {
            $options = $this->getCountryCollection()
                ->setForegroundCountries($this->getTopDestinations())
                ->toOptionArray();
            $this->_configCacheType->save($this->getSerializer()->serialize($options), $cacheKey);
        }
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class
        )->setName(
            $name
        )->setId(
            $id
        )->setTitle(
            $this->escapeHtmlAttr(__($title))
        )->setValue(
            $defValue
        )->setOptions(
            $options
        )->setClass(
            'custom-class'
        )->setExtraParams(
            'data-validate="{\'validate-select\':true}"'
        )->getHtml();

        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('TEST: ' . __METHOD__);
        return $html;
    }


    /**
     * Get serializer
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface
     */
    private function getSerializer()
    {
        if ($this->serializer === null) {
            $this->serializer = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->serializer;
    }
}
```

> **Output**:
> [image]

Comment: I tried above code with setClass and the class is not added

Comment: @Ajith it's working and class name are shown. Please clear the cache or run the Magento command before checking it.

Comment: Hi @Msquare i tried this with same code and run magento command and the class is not added.
addClass works fine in core file.Have you tried this by extended this file?

Comment: @Ajith Try without di.xml preference. Just comment or remove your preference from di.xml and run Magento comment then check it.